# javascript code that makes two button hidden when one is click in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have done a bunch of research and cannot seem to discover the answer. I am hoping you can help me. I have code that shows two buttons, when you click on the "confirm" button, it will display the pop up and make both of the buttons hidden. I cannot seem to make the buttons disappear, the pop up works fine.

```
function confirm() {
alert("Thank you for Confirming the Shipping Address. ");
var confirm_button = document.getElementsByName("confirm");
confirm_button.style.visibility="hidden";
var change_button = document.getElementsByName("change")
change_button.style.visibility="hidden";
```

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" name="confirm" value="Confirm Shipping Address" style="width: 180px; height: 35px"  onclick="confirm()" >
```

Comment: the click on confirm button will cause a submit of the form, so your page will be refreshed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use getElementsBy...it returns a list of elements, even if there is only one. (The plural Elements in getElementsBy gives it away).

So you need to tell it to find a specific one in the list. If there is only one you can use

```
document.getElementsByClassName('blah')[0]
```

OR you can give your element an id and get it that way

```
<input type='button' id='blah'/>
document.getElementById('blah').style.visibility='hidden';
```

Comment: Thank you both so much for your advice, user2782001, that solved my issue!

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'm not a fan of in-line javascript. Here's an example of how to do what you want without it:

```js
//function confirm() {
    //alert("Thank you for Confirming the Shipping Address. ");    
    //var confirm_button = document.getElementsByName("confirm");
    //confirm_button.style.visibility="hidden";
    //var change_button = document.getElementsByName("change")
    //change_button.style.visibility="hidden";
//}

$("#confirm").off().on("click", function(){ // <-- so it doesnt bind on each click
    var changeElem = $("#change");
    $(this).hide();
    changeElem.hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" id="confirm" name="confirm" value="Confirm Shipping Address" style="width: 180px; height: 35px" >
    
    <input type="submit" id="change" value="Change Shipping Address" style="width: 180px; height: 35px" >
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: OR the vanilla javascript way document.myElement.addEventListener('click', confirm);

Comment: I like it... I've hitched my wagon to jQuery but you've got the purest answer.